Firebase Storage with Angular SSR app “ERROR Error: Service storage is not available”
I'm trying to use Firebase Storage in my angular SSR app, but I get
ERROR Error: Service storage is not available initializing the app.
I'm using this code in providers applicationConfig:
provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
provideAuth(() => getAuth(inject(FirebaseApp))),
provideStorage(() => getStorage(inject(FirebaseApp))),

firebaseConfig has all the keys form my project (I copied from firebase configs):
apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
databaseURL: "",
projectId: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "",
appId: "",
locationId: ",

and I'm using this package: "@angular/fire": "^18.0.1"
Also tried to do this:
provideStorage(() => getStorage(inject(FirebaseApp), environment.firebaseConfig.storageBucket)),

but I get the same error.
